# Add a prefix to a string in a SQL server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Hope someone can help with this question. I have a table with image file names sorted in it and some are missing the directory prefix. eg: (without folder info): "some_imagname.jpg" and then with the folder : "/photos/another_imagname.jpg".
I would like to run an update on the table, so that all image names have the folder prefixed added to it, where it is missing.

It's a long story as to how this happened, but suffice to say, I really need to get this updated quite soon.

Many thanks
Hans

Answer (score 6):

A simple update statement with concatenation using the `+` operator and a filter to exclude the records that are already prefixed:

```
UPDATE table
SET column = '/photos/' + column
WHERE column NOT LIKE '/photos/%'
```

Answer (score 1):

With the little information given i'd say:

```
   UPDATE table
         SET name_column = '/photos/' + name_column
   WHERE name_column NOT LIKE '/photos%';
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick. I just rand this and updated some 28,000 records.